# How to Detect NSWindow Maximize or Zoom Event?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

How do you detect when a user clicks the green maximize or zoom (+) button on the NSWindow without using the `NSWindowDidResizeNotification`?

The reason I don't want to use `NSWindowDidResizeNotification` is because that is also triggered repeatedly as the user clicks and drags to manually resize the window. I have some code that I want to execute and it should only fire once when the user **zooms** or **de-zooms** the window using the green button in the top left-hand corner and not many times when manually resizing the window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These two window delegate methods may be useful:

```
- windowWillUseStandardFrame:defaultFrame:
- windowShouldZoom:toFrame:
```

You might also consider subclassing NSWindow and overriding the `zoom:` method.

Comment: That's it! My poor man's workaround was to create a BOOL flag "windowIsResizing" and set it to "YES" on the NSWindowWillStartLiveResizeNotification and back to "NO" on the NSWindowWillEndLiveResizeNotification. Then in the WindowDidResize notification I did "if (!windowIsResizing) ... " and when the window was being manually resized this would prevent the multiple firing of the code that I wanted executed only once, it would only fire when the user pressed the zoom button. But this is much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@EagleOfToledo, based on your question and your comments on Todd Yandell's answer, I think you only need this delegate method:

Swift

```
optional func windowDidEndLiveResize(_ notification: NSNotification)
```

Objective-C

```
- (void)windowDidEndLiveResize:(NSNotification *)notification
```

This method will only be invoked once no matter you click the zoom button or resize manually.